# What are the exact requirements for the parameters of cv.watershed?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use `cv.watershed`. The [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga3267243e4d3f95165d55a618c65ac6e1) says:

```
markers = cv.watershed(image, markers)

Parameters:
    image   Input 8-bit 3-channel image. 
    markers Input/output 32-bit single-channel image (map) of markers. It should have the same size as image .
```

So I do:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
image = (np.random.rand(5,5,3) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
mask = (np.random.rand(5,5) * 3).astype(np.uint32) #(5,5,1) makes no difference
cv.watershed(image, mask)
```

and get `TypeError: markers data type = 6 is not supported`

What is `data type = 6`? What do I need instead? How do I get there?

**Progress:**
`mask = (np.random.rand(5,5) * 3).astype(np.int32)` seems to work. But it would still be great to know a structured approach of how to get there.

Comment: http://ninghang.blogspot.com/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html?m=1

Comment: There's no unsigned int matrix in opencv, just int